# Why am i getting execute binary file error?

Tags: centos, centos6

Hi all i am getting following email every 10 min. as I own the VPS. I am not expert in linux and am learning to manage linux servers. Please help me why am i getting these emails and how to stop them or how to fix the issue i am running CentOS 6 on 123-reg VPS

```
Subject: Cron <root@vpsXXXXXXXX> /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1
/usr/lib64/sa/sa1: line 11: /bin/date: cannot execute binary file
/usr/lib64/sa/sa1: line 13: /bin/date: cannot execute binary file
```

and below email every 1 hour

```
Subject: Cron <root@vpsXXXXXXXX> run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron:

/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron: line 6: /bin/date: cannot execute binary file
/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron: line 6: [: =: unary operator expected
```

Comment: Please don't cross post the SE sites: http://superuser.com/questions/891054/why-am-i-getting-execute-binary-file-error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the /bin/date command is not available in your VPS. You can check with the following command:

```
 ls -l /bin/date
```

Comment: it gives me -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41365188 Mar 17 16:29 /bin/date

Comment: 40 MB!, that's weird. Since when are you receiving these errors? . Please check your logs to see if there is suspicious activity on your server.

Answer (score 0):

> /bin/date: cannot execute binary file

`/bin/date` is either corrupted or not compatible for your OS

> /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron: line 6: [: =: unary operator expected

`0anacron` script is relaying on `date` and that's why it's erroring out (due to your corrupted or incompatible binary)

I'd recommend you to re-install your OS.